# How to properly save data in text field flutter using SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to get the data from the text field via 'Save Data' button then show that data in Text Widget when I click the 'Show Data' button. I'm using SharedPreferences dependency. I'm already done with the code but there's one problem, whenever I click the 'Show Data' button, it only shows the data from the second Text Field like this: LastName null

The result should be: FirstName LastName

> Here's the Save Data

```
saveData(String firstName, String lastName) async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString(firstName, lastName);
}
```

> Here's the Show Data

```
showData(String firstName, String lastName) async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
setState(() {
  fName = prefs.getString(firstName);
  lName = prefs.getString(lastName);
});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shared Preferences lib stores data as <key,value>. In your code you store the value `lastName` under the key `firstName`.
So when you try to find the data with the key `firstName`, it returns the lastName, but when you try to get the data linked to the key `lastName`, it doesn't exist.

This code should lead you to the solution

```
prefs.setString("firstName", firstName);
prefs.setString("lastName", lastName);

...

setState(() {
  fName = prefs.getString("firstName");
  lName = prefs.getString("lastName");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//To save data in shared preference
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('firstName', 'ABC'); //'firstName' is key and 'ABC' is the value 
prefs.setString('lastName', 'D');

//To get data saved in shared preference
String firstname = prefs.getString('firstName') ?? ""; //Pass the key to retrieve saved data
String lastname = prefs.getString('lastName') ?? "";
```